# Replace OR delete part of text using Regular Expressions

Tags: php

i have long text and i want Replace OR delete part of  it .. The beginning of the `<a name="Steps">` and Even `</h2>`
Replace OR delete all this part:

```
<a name="Steps"></a>
<h2> 
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.wikihow.com/index.php?title=Make-a-Balloon-Giraffe&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: Steps" id="gatEditSection" class="button button52 editsection" onmouseover="button_swap(this);" onmouseout="button_unswap(this);" onclick="gatTrack(gatUser,'Edit','Edit_section');" >Edit
</a>
<span> Steps </span>
</h2>
```

Note : the Text contains more than `</h2>` , so i want Replace OR delete Between Even the first tag `</h2>` Comes after the tag `<a name="Steps">` , and Replace OR delete Both tags

```
start :<a name="Steps">text</h2>:end
```

Comment: Tip: surround inline code blocks in backticks ` otherwise the HTML tags won't render.

Comment: Instead of regex, have you looked at [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: thnx , yes i know "DOM" but I did not understand well

Comment: Using regular expressions on XML is one of the classical tarpits, you don't want to jump into. As @DaveChen suggests, DOM is a better alternative. There is plenty of gentle introductions on the net, just Google for "PHP DOM introduction". I found one here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp